# Google Sheet: How to count cells containing "P-" but not in "AP-"

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

My spreadsheet has different types of grading. My goal is to count each type using Count If formula. Counting "AC-", I used `=countif(B:B5,"*AC-*")` and the count is correctly showing 1. However, counting "P-", the formula `=countif(B:B5,"*P-*")` is showing 3 because of results from "P-Redo", "AP-Superb", "P-Poor". I am trying to create a formula to count only "P-" and ignore "AP-Superb". Thanks.

| Name | Type |
| --- | --- |
| Kevin | AC-Mediocre, P-Redo |
| Linda | AB-Decent, AP-Superb |
| Jen | P-Poor |

[Google Sheet Example Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14Hu00zIj9JDEumOQj3qb6ocBJcHSB0L9a7jm1ep95K8/edit#gid=0)

I have tried using regexmatch and used "^" to find the start of a string. `=SUMPRODUCT(REGEXMATCH(B:B5, "(^)P-"))`  but my regexmatch formula is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try with this slight change in your current `regex` formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(REGEXMATCH(B$1:B$5,"\b"&A26))
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Just wanted to confirm, if I wanted to ignore case sensitivity, I would use "(?i)"? So the formula should be "=SUMPRODUCT(REGEXMATCH(B$1:B$5,"\b(?i)"&A26))"?

Comment: yeah that should do it